# vsubst in batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file

In my office they every day double click on the program vsubst to assign a partition of the space on the computer as a drive. I want to make a batch file out of it so they do not have to do this every day. It takes 5 seconds, but 5 people times 5 seconds times 250 working days is 6250 seconds a year!

Can anyone help me out here? This shouldnt be to difficult. I run a windows machine and could put it in the windows task manager.

I guess its something like: Start ....vsubst.exe param param1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. Trial and error got me there. Fill the following line in and place the batch file in your startup programs and you're done :D

```
start path\VSubst.exe NEWDRIVE FOLDERPATH 
exit
```